# Python How to display in 1 window instead of 2

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt5

Im a green in python, and i can't display my gui in 1 window, but it displays 2. How can I display the data in 1 window? I know the quality of the question isn't perfect but i can't seem to know how to do it. How can i put these stuff in one window? Any help would be appreciated.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QFileSystemModel, QTreeView, QWidget, QVBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon

class App(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title = 'PyQt5 file system view - pythonspot.com'
        self.left = 10
        self.top = 10
        self.width = 640
        self.height = 480
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)

        self.model = QFileSystemModel()
        self.model.setRootPath('')
        self.tree = QTreeView()
        self.tree.setModel(self.model)

        self.tree.setAnimated(False)
        self.tree.setIndentation(20)
        self.tree.setSortingEnabled(True)

        self.tree.setWindowTitle("Dir View")
        self.tree.resize(640, 480)

        windowLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        windowLayout.addWidget(self.tree)
        self.setLayout(windowLayout)

        self.show()

class Example(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.initUI()


    def initUI(self):

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 500, 520)
        self.setWindowTitle('Total Commander')
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('tcmd.ico'))        

        self.statusBar()

        menubar = self.menuBar()
        fileMenu = menubar.addMenu('&File')
        fileMenu = menubar.addMenu('&Mark')
        fileMenu = menubar.addMenu('&Commands')
        fileMenu = menubar.addMenu('&Net')
        fileMenu = menubar.addMenu('&Show')
        fileMenu = menubar.addMenu('&Configuration')
        fileMenu = menubar.addMenu('&Start')
        # fileMenu = menubar.addMenu('&                                    ')
        fileMenu = menubar.addMenu('&Help')

        self.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ap = App()
    ex = Example()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: This is how it looks]

Hello, Im a green in python, and i can't display my gui in 1 window, but it displays 2. How can I display the data in 1 window? I know the quality of the question isn't perfect but i can't seem to know how to do it. How can i put these stuff in one window? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: QWidget can be used as a window of it's own and since it's not being added to something as a child it's showing up. I'm not familiar enough to help beyond this, but I imagine you'll need to have the window add the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QMainWindow, QApplication, QFileSystemModel, 
                             QTreeView, QWidget, QVBoxLayout)
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon

class App(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title = 'PyQt5 file system view - pythonspot.com'
        self.left = 10
        self.top = 10
        self.width = 640
        self.height = 480
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)

        self.model = QFileSystemModel()
        self.model.setRootPath('')
        self.tree = QTreeView()
        self.tree.setModel(self.model)

        self.tree.setAnimated(False)
        self.tree.setIndentation(20)
        self.tree.setSortingEnabled(True)

        self.tree.setWindowTitle("Dir View")
        self.tree.resize(640, 480)

        windowLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        windowLayout.addWidget(self.tree)
        self.setLayout(windowLayout)

#        self.show()

class Example(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.initUI()
# + vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv        
        self.centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)  # Sets the given widget to be the main window's central widget.
        self.ap = App()

        layout = QVBoxLayout(self.centralWidget)
        layout.addWidget(self.ap)
# + ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

    def initUI(self):

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 500, 520)
        self.setWindowTitle('Total Commander')
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('tcmd.ico'))        

        self.statusBar()

        menubar = self.menuBar()
        fileMenu = menubar.addMenu('&File')
        fileMenu = menubar.addMenu('&Mark')
        fileMenu = menubar.addMenu('&Commands')
        fileMenu = menubar.addMenu('&Net')
        fileMenu = menubar.addMenu('&Show')
        fileMenu = menubar.addMenu('&Configuration')
        fileMenu = menubar.addMenu('&Start')
        # fileMenu = menubar.addMenu('&                                    ')
        fileMenu = menubar.addMenu('&Help')
#        self.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
#    ap = App()
    ex = Example()
    ex.show()                          # +
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: You are a god, thank you, got maybe any tutorials like this ? Because i wouldn't figure it out for days how to do it. And u've done it so easly

Comment: @S.Nick Please, would you care to improve your answer by **explaining** it? This just "solves" the OP question, but it does not really answer by explaining *why* your code works, and you should know better that "that *why*" is what StackOverflow is about.